# How to create data table using dynamic dates functions like now() or ago()?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there a way to create a data table using dynamic dates function like now() or ago()? I am not sure it's possible or just an issue of finding the right syntax.

Works

```
let Logs = datatable(timestamp: datetime) [
    datetime(2022-12-02 2:00:00.00),
    datetime(2022-12-02 6:00:00.00),
];
```

Does not work

```
let Logs = datatable(timestamp: datetime) [
    now(),
    datetime(now()- ago(3h)),
];
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

*datatable* accept only literals (no expressions, no functions).

You can use the [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) operator with multiple [print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/printoperator) statements:

```
union 
    (print 1, now())
   ,(print 2, ago(3h))
| project-rename id = print_0, timestamp = print_1
```

| id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-02-15T05:29:23.2203689Z |
| 1 | 2023-02-15T08:29:23.2203689Z |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAyvNy8zPU%20BSAAKNgqLMvBIFQx2FvPxyDU1NkKAOVNBIRyExPV/DOAMoXKNQUJSflZpcoluUmpeYm6qQmaJgqwBWF2%20go1CSmZtaXJKYWwAXNAQAfYO3wWUAAAA=)

P.S.
`datetime(now()- ago(3h))` is wrong.

1. *datetime* accept only literal.
2. `now() - ago(3h)` is equal to *3h*.
   Use `ago(3h)` or `now() - 3h`